# Laravel 5.4 - How to get child data from custom intermediate table model (pivot)?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have M-M eloquent relationship: Member - Comments - Album.

### Table

Member:
id

Album:
id

Comment:
id, member_id, album_id, reply_to, text

---

Column "reply_to" in the Comment table contains the ID of the comment (it's for comment replies)

**Model**

```
//Member
...
public function comments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Album', 'comments', 'member_id', 'member_id')->using('App\Comment');
}


//Album
...
public function comments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Member', 'comments', 'album_id', 'member_id')
    ->withPivot('id', 'reply_to',  'text', 'created_at')
    ->using('App\Comment');
}

//Comment
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
class Comment extends Pivot
...
public function album(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Album');
    }

    public function member(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Member');
    }
public function scopeChildren(){
        return $this->where('reply_to', $this->id);
    }
```

Here is how I try to get the comment list:

```
@foreach($album->comments as $commenter)
// $commenter->pivot is working
@endforeach
```

The question is, how to get comment data based on "reply_to" using `scopeChildren()` from the code in above?
Counting data is working:
`$commenter->pivot->children()->count()`

But get data is not working:
`$commenter->pivot->children()->get()`

`dd($commenter->pivot->children())` is return this:

```
`Builder {#418 ▼
  #query: Builder {#419 ▶}
  #model: Comment {#405 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:11 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}`
```

Also when call this method `$commenter->pivot->children()->get()` its return this message:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given,

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @NitishKumar Nope. Because of the deadline.. I am change it eloquent relations from "Many-to-Many" to "One-to-Many" instead.

Comment: Any update on this matter?